# Aggregation Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB and Mongoose for my project.
I have a messages collection storing messages between customers and a pool of admins. Customers generate questions and admins generate the replies. The data structure is this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fa0b9c98868ee59a6981f8"),
    "from" : ObjectId("56c3623801582ce05d5fe870"),
    "value" : "Question 1???",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-03-29T04:59:08.799Z"),
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fa0bb198868ee59a6981f9"),
    "from" : ObjectId("56f90ce398868ee59a6981ee"),
    "value" : "Question A?",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-03-29T04:59:29.769Z"),
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fa0bcf2c8db147579f5a51"),
    "to" : ObjectId("56c3623801582ce05d5fe870"),
    "from" : ObjectId("56c167d1912bdff65bc0644b"),
    "value" : "Answer 1",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-03-29T04:59:59.320Z"),
}
```

In the above example we have 3 messages:

- Customer Id=...870 ask a question "1"
- Customer Id=...1ee ask a question "A"
- Admin Id=...44b replies to question "1" from Customer id=...870
- Question "A" from Customer is unanswered

I need to list and count unanswered questions.

***UPDATE:*** It is enough for me to get "The list of messages rouped by customers (not admins), that doesn't have an admin response at a later time"

From a previous query I already have an array of Admin Ids (objectIdArray) so I can check if a message came from an admin with the following expression:

```
{from: {$in: objectIdArray}}
```

I am trying to get it all with a single query:

```
Custmsg.aggregate([
    {$match: { $and: [ {archiveDate: {$exists: false}} ] } },
    {$group: { _id: {'from': '$from', 'to': '$to'},
                info: {
                        $push: {    lastMessage: '$date',
                                    lastValue: '$value',
                                    to: '$to'
                                }
                        }
            }
    },
    {$sort: {lastMessage: -1}}
])
```

And getting this results:

```
[
   {
      "_id":{
         "from":"56c167d1912bdff65bc0644b",
         "to":"56c3623801582ce05d5fe870"
      },
      "info":[
         {
            "lastMessage":"2016-03-29T04:59:59.320Z",
            "lastValue":"Answer 1",
            "to":"56c3623801582ce05d5fe870"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":{
         "from":"56f90ce398868ee59a6981ee"
      },
      "info":[
         {
            "lastMessage":"2016-03-29T04:59:29.769Z",
            "lastValue":"Question A?"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":{
         "from":"56c3623801582ce05d5fe870"
      },
      "info":[
         {
            "lastMessage":"2016-03-29T04:59:08.799Z",
            "lastValue":"Question 1???"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

But I dont know how to finish.
Is it possible to do it in a single query or how would you do it?

Comment: Where is the `archiveDate` in your data schema?

Comment: It's probably not a great model for what you want. If I see the intent clearly you want to "pair up" the answer to the question, and then basically see which questions remain unanswered. You would be better of keeping "answers" as an array on the "question", and then it would be easy to just test for questions with an empty answers array. Trying to make that happen with this structure is basically asking for a "self join", which is only really possible in the latest MongoDB release, but also not really efficient.

Comment: You also have another inherrent structural problem in that the "answer" only identifies the "asker" and not the "question". i.e "Third" document is in response to the "First" but only because the "to" in the "answer" references the "from" in the "question". Again, structuring with an array of answers directly on the question solves that issue.

Comment: @zangw. The schema exposed here is a simplification. Customers only can have a single "conversation" at a time. Admins can archive conversations. When conversations are archived, the archiveDate property is populated.

Comment: @Blackes Seven. I don't need to pair questions and answers. It is enough for me to get "The list of messages grouped by customers (not admins), that doesn't have an admin response later in time"

Comment: As Blacks point out, your current document schema is hard to do aggregation to meet your requirement. Here is one solution to get all ids of answered questions, `> db.message.aggregate([{$lookup: {from: 'message', localField: 'to', foreignField: 'from', as: 'QA'}}, {$project: {QA: 1, sizeofQA: {$size: '$QA'}}}, {$match:{sizeofQA: {$gt: 0}}}, {$group: {_id: null, idOfA: {$push: '$_id'}, idOfQ: {$push: '$QA._id'}}}])` with `$lookup` to do self join under mongo v3.2.1.